# No Exported Member when run unit test

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angular-cli

i use @angular/cli (upgrated to last version). i have imported some plugins in my Component like `import layers = L.control.layers;`, Everything works fine. But when I run the test with ng test, I have errors like

```
ERROR in MY_COMPONENET.component.ts (14,19): Namespace 'L' has no exported member 'control'.
```

any idea how can i resolve that.

Comment: Did you update the unit tests to use the same library?

Comment: i use nom a 1.4.1 version of karma and the 2.5.2 of jasmine. you think that i want to update its?

Comment: I think the problem is to explain to Karma and Jasmine that the **leaflet** type "L" can export objects as control, icon, layer, Marker...

Comment: You may want to include the code for the unit test that is failing in your question. Otherwise, this is just guesswork.

Comment: I found it. The solution is that I have to define the types to export in **tsconfig.ts** file like `"types": [ "leaflet", "nvd3", ... ]` thx @R.Richards